# Fastlane iOS Automating Notification Screenshots

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I would love to create automated screenshots of the Lockscreen of a simulator for every device & language.
I thought about doing a hacky way by displaying a local notification after 2 seconds, lock the screen using UITests, undim the screen and take a screenshot.
I have not been able to successfully do that though so I was wondering if anybody knows a better way to do automated notification screenshots for iOS or a service that allows me to configure the lockscreen?

Another idea I had is to use a stock image and display it when using the screenshot UI Test, however I‘m not sure this will look good on every device.

Thanks for any help